# How to put matched part into end of the string?

Tags: php, regex

I'm trying to figure out how to put matched part of a string to the end of the string in php.

For example, let's say that we have string like this:

```
"<span>Foo</span> rest of the string"
```

At final, I'd like to obtain this:

```
"rest of the string Foo"
```

Code:

```
$string = "<span>Foo</span> rest of the string";
//$str = preg_replace("/<span>(.*?)<\/span>/","$1",$string);
```

I know that matched part is represented by $1 but I could not find a way to put it to the end.

Comment: You have to put the rest of string in another capture group. Then swap the groups.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$1` refers to the first captured group (a capture group is marked by a pair of parantheses)
Now you just need to capture the rest of the string in another group (`$2`) and then put it in the replaced pattern like so:
`$str = preg_replace("/<span>(.*?)<\/span>\s*(.*)/","$2 $1",$string);`

Comment: I've tried the following code before I asked the question which did not work. Thanks to your answer, I realized that it is because of the question mark I put at the end of the pattern. Can you explain why?
`$string = "<span>Foo</span> rest of the string";
$str = preg_replace("/<span>(.*?)<\/span>(.*?)/","$2 $1",$string);`

Comment: Normal `*` without modifying flag is greedy match and will try to consume as much as possible. `*?` is lazy match and only matches more when backtracked.  
See more: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2301285/what-do-lazy-and-greedy-mean-in-the-context-of-regular-expressions

Comment: And so in your code it will only replace the part `<span>Foo</span>␣` of the string, capturing `␣` as the 2nd group, and swap only that single space up in front of `Foo`